# Association rules between many continuous variables

Tags: r, algorithm, machine-learning, associations, arules

I have a large dataset and I'm trying to mining association rules between the variables.

My problem is that I have 160 variables among which I have to look for the association rules and also I have more than 1800 item-sets.

Furthermore my variables are continuous variables. To mining association rules, I usually used the apriori algorithm, but as is well known, this algorithm requires the use of categorical variables.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what kind of algorithm I can use in this case?

A restricted example of my dataset is the following:

```
ID_Order   Model     ordered quantity
A.1        typeX     20
A.1        typeZ     10
A.1        typeY     5
B.2        typeX     16
B.2        typeW     12
C.3        typeZ     1
D.4        typeX     8
D.4        typeG     4
...
```

My goal would be mining association rules and correlation between different products, maybe with a neural network algorithm in R Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: look at [arules](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create transactions from your dataset like this:

```
library(dplyr)
```

This function is used to get the transactions per `ID_Order`

```
concat <- function(x) {
  return(list(as.character(x)))

}
```

Group `df` by `ID_Order` and concatenate. `pull()` returns the concatenated `Model`s in a list.

```
a_list <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID_Order) %>% 
  summarise(concat = concat(Model)) %>%
  pull(concat)
```

Set names to `ID_Order`:

```
names(a_list) <- unique(df$ID_Order)
```

Then you can use the package `arules`:

Get object of `transactions` class:

```
transactions <- as(a_list, "transactions")
```

Extract rules. You can set minimum support and minimum confidence in `supp` and `conf` resp.

```
rules <- apriori(transactions, 
                 parameter = list(supp = 0.1, conf = 0.5, target = "rules"))
```

To inspect the rules use:

```
inspect(rules)
```

And this is what you get:

```
     lhs              rhs     support confidence lift      count
[1]  {}            => {typeZ} 0.50    0.50       1.0000000 2    
[2]  {}            => {typeX} 0.75    0.75       1.0000000 3    
[3]  {typeW}       => {typeX} 0.25    1.00       1.3333333 1    
[4]  {typeG}       => {typeX} 0.25    1.00       1.3333333 1    
[5]  {typeY}       => {typeZ} 0.25    1.00       2.0000000 1    
[6]  {typeZ}       => {typeY} 0.25    0.50       2.0000000 1    
[7]  {typeY}       => {typeX} 0.25    1.00       1.3333333 1    
[8]  {typeZ}       => {typeX} 0.25    0.50       0.6666667 1    
[9]  {typeY,typeZ} => {typeX} 0.25    1.00       1.3333333 1    
[10] {typeX,typeY} => {typeZ} 0.25    1.00       2.0000000 1    
[11] {typeX,typeZ} => {typeY} 0.25    1.00       4.0000000 1
```

Comment: Hi @clemens, thanks for your answer is very detailed, but when I tried to run the script I get an error.
When I run this part of code `a_list <- df %>% 
  group_by(ID_Order) %>% 
  summarise(concat = concat(Model)) %>%
  pull(concat)` I obtain this error:
`Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘pull’ for signature ‘"tbl_df"’`
I saw that it was due to a conflict between packages, maybe git2r and dplyr,
but I could not solve the problem, how did you get it? Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, but you can try to explicitly use `dplyr::pull(concat)` instead of `pull(concat)`. I am using R 3.4.1 and dplyr 0.7.4

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

From the example section of `? transactions`:

```
## example 4: creating transactions from a data.frame with 
## transaction IDs and items (by converting it into a list of transactions first) 
a_df3 <- data.frame(
  TID = c(1,1,2,2,2,3), 
  item=c("a","b","a","b","c","b")
  )
a_df3
trans4 <- as(split(a_df3[,"item"], a_df3[,"TID"]), "transactions")
trans4
inspect(trans4)
```